# Random music player onClick Android

Tags: java, android, media-player

So I'm making this Star Wars fan app on Android.

I've got this image of Yoda and a button for him. When you tap it, now he says a sentence (with the mediaplayer). 
The thing is, I want him to say different things so I got 4 different MP3 files,but how do I let it choose randomly which one to play when the user clicks on the button?

This is my code for now:

```
package be.ehb.arnojansens.simpleFrag;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import be.ehb.arnojansens.fragmentexampleii.R;

public class SimpleFragmentActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_fragment);

        final Button advice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YodaAdvice);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yodamessage);

        advice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hmm Busy I Am", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mp.start();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Have You considered what if user will start tapping Yoda fiercely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 4 final messages

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yodamessage);
final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yodamessage1);//File names would be different I guess
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yodamessage2);
final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yodamessage3);
```

Also you need a random

```
Random random=new Random();
```

And then in your on click method

```
int r = random.nextInt(4);
if(r==0){
mp.start();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hmm Busy I Am", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
if(r==1){
mp1.start();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I'm hungry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
if(r==2){
mp2.start();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My droid now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
if(r==3){
mp3.start();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not droid you are looking for", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```